# Why is my output corrupted?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'm using the following function to return the current amount of memory installed:

```
const char* Aries::Memory::GetInstalledMemory() {
    MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;
    statex.dwLength = sizeof(statex);
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&statex);
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << statex.ullTotalPhys / (1024 * 1024 * 1024);
    return ss.str().c_str();
}
```

I am using it in conjunction of another `stringstream` and output it to the screen:

```
CryLogAlways("$1[Aries | System]$2 Probe system.");
Aries::Memory *pMem = new Aries::Memory();
stringstream ss;
ss << "$1[Aries | System]$2 Result of probe: installed memory is ";
ss << pMem->GetInstalledMemory();
ss << "GB.";
```

The expected output is:

> $1[Aries | System]$2 Result of probe: installed memory is 32.00GB.

The output I get is:

> Ö

Meanwhile if I tweak the function so that it returns a `DOUBLE`, it works fine:

```
DOUBLE Aries::Memory::GetInstalledMemory() {
    MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;
    statex.dwLength = sizeof(statex);
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&statex);
    return statex.ullTotalPhys / (1024 * 1024 * 1024);
}
```

It seems that some error with casting using `ostringstream` inside the `GetInstalledMemory()` function is causing this. However I need to return a `const char *`.

The output of `GetInstalledMemory` seems to be corrupting the entire `stringstream` where it is used; where is this going wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Would be quite nice for the drive-by downvoter to explain themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ss.str()` returns a `std::string` object, but in your code it will only exist as a temporary during that one line of code. Then you call `c_str()` which gives a pointer to the memory which that temporary string owns. But as soon as your function returns that memory becomes invalid to access since the temporary was destroyed.

A good solution is to change `GetInstalledMemory` to return a `std::string` object instead of a character pointer. Then it can just `return ss.str();` and the string objects will take care of everything.

Comment: A nice explanation, cheers (I plan to accept yours as it is the better answer, although Ed Heal answered first)! I never thought of it that way but it makes perfect sense.